# xcode/iOS: UITextField overlaid onto UITableViewCell with same frame does not match

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

To allow high-performance editing of `UITableView` cells I maintain a single `UITextField` which is displayed/hidden as needed. I've extended `UITableView` so that double-tapping a cell enters text edit mode, at which stage the text field is added as a subview to the tapped `UITableViewCell` and becomes the first responder. The cell textLabel is purposefully hidden at this point.

My issue is: I set the **same frame** and **same font** for my `UITableViewCell` and the `UITextField`, yet the two do not exactly overlap. I have produced an image illustrating this behaviour: the left side shows on top the `UITableViewCell` textLabel, below this is the `UITextField` overlaid with cell textLabel hidden, and on the right are both made visible.

[image: inexact overlay]

I'm not keen on "fudge factor" value fixes, so can anyone tell me what's missing?

I am running the app under **`iOS 4.2`** in the xcode iPad simulator.

Many thanks!

Comment: Make sure there isn't a text shadow set.

Answer (score 0):

Textfield might just align its content differently. Give the textfid a border to see if it really has the same size as your cell's content view (are you adding to that? Or to the cell's view?)
If the textfield and the cell match, I don't see a problem using a fudge factor.